# My JavaScript isn't changing className property

Tags: javascript, dom-events, classname

Here is the main part of my code attempting to toggle class on a p tag (info) on click of my button (btn). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have never used the `className` property before so I'm not sure if I'm missing something simple, or if there is fundamental error in my logic trying to attempt this.

```
var handler = function(event){
  if(info.className === 'on'){
    info.className='off';
  }else{
    info.className='on';
  }
};

btn.addEventListener('click', handler);
```

Comment: Where is `info` declared?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. [Here's a jsFiddle with a demo of your code working](http://jsfiddle.net/peterolson/4cmzLubh/1/).

Comment: I used document.getElementById to obtain info and btn. I had this working using a different method just changing the info.style.display, but I'm trying to figure out how I would implement this by changing the className.

Comment: Thank you. I had it write I just accidently had a curly brace on my else statement out of place in my actual code and somehow didn't notice. Thanks for confirming my logic though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works just fine. You can run the snippet below to see that it works.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn"),
    info = document.getElementById("info");

var handler = function (event) {
    if (info.className === 'on') {
        info.className = 'off';
    } else {
        info.className = 'on';
    }
};

btn.addEventListener('click', handler);
```

```css
.on {
    background-color: red;
}
.off {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button id=btn>Button</button>
<p id=info>Info</p>
```

Comment: Thank you. I had a curly brace out of place in my actual code. I thought I was doing something wrong. Thank you for using the run example feature on this site I haven't seen that yet so that was useful to find out about.

Answer (score 0):

What is info is it an id? if yes, and if you are using simple javascript then call it as document.getElementById('info') or if jquery then $('#info').

However it also sounds like all the names element and classnames (info, on, off) appearing as a builtin keywords. Better change their names and try again something like infoElem, onClass, offClass and these classes should be renamed again similarly in your style sheet.